# Why extra lines in PDOS plot using xmgrace

Tags: quantum-espresso, visualization-software, density-of-states

Input file for 221 MoS2

```
&projwfc        

prefix       = 'MoS2', 
outdir       = './out',
deltae       = 0.1,
filproj      = 'MoS2-pdos.dat',
```

Another file run is plot-pdos.gnu

```
set autoscale         # scale axes automatically
unset log             # remove any log-scaling
unset label           # remove any previous labels
set xtic auto         # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto         # set ytics automatically
set title "Density of states (DOS) of MoS2 crystal"
set xlabel "Energy (ev)"
set ylabel "PDOS"
set arrow 1 from -1.1888,0 to -1.1888,2 nohead ls 10 dt 2      #Fermienegy
plot "atom_Mo_s.dat" using 1:2 title 'Mo s orbital' with linespoints,\
     "atom_Mo_p.dat" using 1:2 title 'Mo p orbital' with linespoints,\
     "atom_Mo_d.dat" using 1:2 title 'Mo d orbital' with linespoints,\
     "atom_S_s.dat" using 1:2 title 'S s orbital' with linespoints,\
     "atom_S_p.dat" using 1:2 title 'S p orbital' with linespoints,\
     "atom_Mo_tot.dat" using 1:2 title 'Mo total' with linespoints,\
     "atom_S_tot.dat" using 1:2 title 'S total' with linespoints
pause -1 "Hit any key to continue\n"   #so that the code doesn't exit automatically
```

The correct PDOS should look like this
[image: Correct PDOS]

While ploting pdos output using xmgrace, I am getting additional slanting lines my plot. How do resolve this?

[image: Incorrect PDOS]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It will help other users to address your question if you add some more context. For example: do you think the issue was actually with xmgrace or your quantum espresso calculation? What is the input file you used for your calculation/what system are you simulating? What do you think the plot should look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check your data file once, you can verify this plot  again in excel.

Comment: I would agree with Pranav, it seems likely this is an issue with the output data rather than something xmgrace related (and the xmgrace issues would probably be off-topic for the site). Also, if it isn't too much to ask, could you crop the PDOS plots? They have a lot of surrounding white space, which makes the post look strange and the plots difficult to read.

Comment: Your data isn't sorted in order of energy. xmgrace draws lines between points simply based on their order in the file, so what's happened here is a point at low energy is next to a point at high energy, so it's drawn a line between them.

Comment: Yes I checked the data file and also i find that "error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64" while running sumpdos.x So, have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. After giving correct path i have to run. Thankyou

Comment: Hi user4777! Have you been able to solve this problem since January? Do you have any update? Either way, I wonder if you could remove some of the unnecessary whitespace from your images in this question?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.